# Handle click on child layout of dynamically created layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

Hello devs I am making a dynamic view in which I am adding a text view and a image view and on click on image view the layout should be deleted. But the problem is that when I click on the child of the layout it takes two click to delete.

Any help will be appreciated.

the layout code is :

```
LinearLayout a = new LinearLayout(mContext);
                a.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                TextView itemNameTV = new TextView(mContext);
                itemNameTV.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                itemNameTV.setText(myInventoryItemRs.getQuantity());
                ImageView delete = new ImageView(mContext);
                itemNameTV.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                delete.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_close, null));
                holder.item_quantity_editText.setText("");
                myInventoryItemRs.setQuantity("");
                a.addView(itemNameTV);
                a.addView(delete);
                holder.add_more_items.addView(a);
```

and click listener on more items

```
moreItems.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            try {
                // On first click this is called.
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Layout outer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int count = moreItems.getChildCount();
                Log.e(TAG, "onClick: " + count);
                View nv;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    try {
                        nv = moreItems.getChildAt(i);
                        ImageView delete = (ImageView) ((LinearLayout) nv).getChildAt(1);
                        View finalNv1 = nv;
                        delete.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
                
                // On Second click this is called.
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Layout inner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            moreItems.removeView(finalNv1);
                        });
                        TextView tnv = (TextView) ((LinearLayout) nv).getChildAt(0);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onClick: " + e);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onClick: " + e);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your view structure looks like it
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7JAE.png

You can set OnClickListener in each ImageView when you create it. Like this.

```
delete.setOnClickListener(view ->
            ((ViewGroup)view.getParent().getParent()).removeView((View) view.getParent())
    );
```

It is not the best decision but it should work